# Groovy convert a flat list of lists to a hierarchy

Tags: groovy

Assuming we have a flat list of lists in groovy, like the following:

```
[[id: 1,title: A],[id: 2, title: B],[id: 3, title: C]]
```

What is the fastest way to transform it in a hierarchy where B is children to A and C is Children to B?

I can do this with iterations, but since groovy is so creative, I am wondering if there is a smarter way.

Comment: I failed to see, how the object shall be structured. By id? Give more examples

Comment: @injecteer This is a list containing lists. List 1 will have an additional field *child* which contains list-2, list-2 a field *child* which contain list-3. In the end the new list will contain only one element with a child and so on.

Comment: this is clear. the question is, how would the children be nested? by `id`? or by `title`?

Comment: anyway, you will have to use iterations here. Groovy's magic collection methods do not provide this kind of functionality out of box.

Comment: That is not a List of List.  It is a List of Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing if you don't mind mutating your original list and its elements:

```
def list = [[id: 1,title: 'A'],[id: 2, title: 'B'],[id: 3, title: 'C']]

list.inject( [:] ) { prev, next ->
  if( prev ) {
      prev.child = next
  }
  next
}

assert list.head() == [id:1, title:'A', child:[id:2, title:'B', child:[id:3, title:'C']]]
```